# How to remove newlines between data of each record which are located between 2 patterns?

Tags: sed

I have a large file to parse and reformat, preferably with `sed` (under bash). The file contains repetitive sequences starting with `PATTERN_START` and ending with `PATTERN_END`. These sequences are intermixed with other text that I have to keep unchanged. In the sequences, there are several records (numbered from 1 to *n*, where *n* can be from 1 to 12). A record is a group of lines beginning with a line of the form `Record i`, where *i* is an integer between 1 and *n*, and ends with another such line (`Record (i+1)`) or a `PATTERN_END` line. The length of a record can be from 1 line to 30 lines.

Here's a generic representation of an input file:

```
unrelated data          (possibly many lines)                      ⎤
PATTERN_START                                                      |
Record 1                                  ⎤                        |
data for Record 1  ⎤  (up to 30 lines)    |                        |  (many repetitions)
      ︙           ⎦                      |  (up to 12 records)    |
Record 2                                 |                        |
data for Record 2                        ⎦                         |
PATTERN_END                                                       ⎦
unrelated data          (possibly many lines)
```

So, I would like, ONLY for the records located between `PATTERN_START` and `PATTERN_END`, to have all the data lines of each record gathered on the `Record` line.

Can anybody help?

Hereunder is a sample of the file that I have to parse, and the kind of result I would like to have:

#### Input

```
Blabla
Blabla
PATTERN_OTHER
Record 1         <- record not between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => do not touch it
Data
Data
PATTERN_END
Blabla
PATTERN_START
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line
Data
Data
Data
Record 2         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line
Data
Data
Record 3         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line
Data
Data
Data
Data
PATTERN_END
Blabla
Blabla
Blabla
Blabla
PATTERN_START
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line
Data
Data
Data
PATTERN_END
Blabla
Blabla
PATTERN_OTHER
Record 1         <- record not between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => do not touch it
Data
Data
Record 2         <- record not between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => do not touch it
Data
PATTERN_END
Blabla
Blabla
PATTERN_START
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line
Data
Record 2         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line
Data
Data
Data
PATTERN_END
Blabla
Blabla
```

#### Output

```
Blabla
Blabla
PATTERN_OTHER
Record 1         <- was not between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => not modified
Data
Data
PATTERN_END
Blabla
PATTERN_START
Record 1 Data Data Data        <- record data grouped in one line
Record 2 Data Data             <- record data grouped in one line
Record 3 Data Data Data Data   <- record data grouped in one line
PATTERN_END
Blabla
Blabla
Blabla
Blabla
PATTERN_START
Record 1 Data Data Data        <- record data grouped in one line
PATTERN_END
Blabla
Blabla
PATTERN_OTHER
Record 1         <- was not between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => not modified
Data
Data
Record 2         <- was not between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => not modified
Data
PATTERN_END
Blabla
Blabla
PATTERN_START
Record 1 Data                  <- record data grouped in one line
Record 2 Data Data Data        <- record data grouped in one line
PATTERN_END
Blabla
Blabla
```

Comment: consider using `awk` instead of `sed`

Comment: special characters in either pattern could have an impact on ways to do this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think this is what you want using GNU sed

```
 sed -n '/^PATTERN_START/,/^PATTERN_END/{
         //!{H;/^Record/!{x;s/\n\([^\n]*\)$/ \1/;x}};
         /^PATTERN_START/{h};/^PATTERN_END/{x;p;x;p};d
         };p' file
```

#### Explanation

```
sed -n #Non printing


'/^PATTERN_START/,/^PATTERN_END/{
#If the line falls between these two patterns execute the next block

  //!{
  #If the previous pattern matched from the line above is not on matched(so skip 
         the start and end lines), then execute next block

        H;
        #append the line to the hold buffer, so this appends all lines between 
       #`/^PATTERN_START/` and `/^PATTERN_END/` not including those.

        /^Record/!{
        #If the line does not begin with record then execute next block

            x;s/\n\([^\n]*\)$/ \1/;x
            #Swap current line with pattern buffer holding all our other lines 
            #up to now.Then remove the last newline. As this only executed when 
            #record is not matched it just removes the newline from the start 
            #of `data`.
            #The line is then put switched back into the hold buffer.

        }
        #End of not record block

    }; 
    #End of previous pattern match block

    /^PATTERN_START/{h};

    #If line begins with `PATTERN_START` then the hold buffer is overwritten 
    #with this line removing all the previous matched lines.

    /^PATTERN_END/{x;p;x;p}
    #If line begins with `PATTERN_END` the swap in our saved lines, print them,
    #then swap back in the PATTERN END line and print that as well.

    ;d
    #Delete all the lines within the range, as we print them explicitly in the 
    #Pattern end block above


         };p' file
         # Print everything that's not in the range print, and the name of the file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot User112638726, terdon, rpax, nitishch, and don_crissti !

Answer (score 6):

This was the best I could come up with:

```
sed -n '/^PATTERN_START/, /^PATTERN_END/{
            /^PATTERN_START/{x;s/^.*$//;x};
            /^Record/{x;/^\n/{s/^\n//p;d};s/\n/ /gp};
            /^PATTERN_END/{x;/^\n/{s/^\n//p;d};s/\n/ /gp;g;p};
            /^Record/!H
        };   
        /^PATTERN_START/, /^PATTERN_END/!p'
```

**Explanation**

I assume you are familiar with the idea of hold space and pattern space in `sed`. In this solution, we will be doing lot of manipulations in pattern space. So, first point is to disable automatic printing with `-n` option and print wherever required.

First task is to join all the lines that are between `Record` lines.

Consider the following file:

```
a
b
Record 1
c
d
Record 2
e
f
Record 3
```

After joining lines, we want it to be

```
a
b
Record 1 c d
Record 2 e f
Record 3
```

So, here is the plan:

1. We read a line, append it to the hold space.
2. If the line starts with `Record`, it means that the previous record has finished and a new record has started. So we print out the hold space, flush it and start with point 1 again.

Point 1 is implemented by the code `/^Record/!H` (5th line in the command). What it means is "if the line doesn't start with `Record`, add a new line to the hold space and append this line to the hold space".

Point 2 can be implemented by the code
    /^Record/{x;s/\n/ /gp;}
where `x` swaps hold and pattern spaces, `s` command replaces all `\n`s with s and `p` flag prints the pattern space. Usage of `x` also has the advantage that now the hold space contains the current `Record` line so that we can begin another cycle of points 1 and 2.

But, this has a problem. In the given example, there are two lines
    a
    b
before the first `Record` line. We don't want to substitute `\n` for  in these lines. Since they don't begin with `Record`, according to point 1, `\n` is added to hold space and then these lines are appended. So, if the first character of the hold space is `\n`, it means that no `Record` has been encountered before and we should not substitute `\n` with .  This is done with the command

```
/^\n/{s/^\n//p;d}
```

So the entire command becomes

```
/^Record/{x;/^\n/{s/^\n//p;d};s/\n/ /gp};
```

Now, the second complication is, we want to join lines, even if a `Record` line is not terminated by a `Record` line but by a `PATTERN_END` line. We want to do the exact same things as in point 2, even when the line starts with `PATTERN_END`. So the command becomes

```
/^PATTERN_END/{x;/^\n/?s/^\n//p;d};s/\n/ /gp}
```

But, there is a problem with this. As in the case of `Record` lines, the `PATTERN_END` line now ends up in the hold space. But we know that there will be no more joining of lines after `PATTERN_END` line. So, we can print this out. So, we bring the `PATTERN_END` line to pattern space with `g` and print it with `p`. So the final command becomes

```
/^PATTERN_END/{x;/^\n/?s/^\n//p;d};s/\n/ /gp;g;p}
```

Next issue is with the `PATTERN_START` lines. In the above explanation we assumed that at the start, hold space is empty. But after a `PATTERN_END`, there is something in the hold space. (That something is just `PATTERN_END` line). When we start a new cycle with `PATTERN_START`, we want to clear the hold space.

So, what we do is when we encounter `PATTERN_START`, swap the contents of hold and pattern spaces, clear the pattern space and swap again. This makes hold space clean. This is exactly what the following command does:

```
/^PATTERN_START/{x;s/^.*$//;x}
```

The final stroke is that we want to do all this fiddling only between `PATTERN_START` and `PATTERN_END` lines. Others, we just print them. This is done by the commands

```
/^PATTERN_START/, /^PATTERN_END/{
    ----above commands go here----
};
/^PATTERN_START/, /^PATTERN_END/!p
```

Put all these together and this gives the final command :)

Answer (score 3):

Other ways with `sed`:

```
sed '/PATTERN_START/,/PATTERN_END/{   # in this range
//!{                                  # if not start or end of range
/^Record/{                            # if line matches Record
x                                     # exchange pattern and hold space
/^$/d                                 # if pattern space is empty, delete it
s/\n/ /g                              # replace newlines with spaces
}
/^Record/!{                           # if line doesn't match Record
H                                     # append it to hold space
d                                     # then delete it
}
}
/PATTERN_END/{                        # at end of range
x                                     # exchange pattern and hold space
s/\n/ /g                              # replace newlines with space
G                                     # append hold space to pattern space
x                                     # exchange again
s/.*//                                # empty pattern space
x                                     # exchange again > empty line in hold space
}
}' infile
```

or

```
sed '/PATTERN_START/,/PATTERN_END/{     # same as above
//!{                                    # same as above
: again
N                                       # pull the next line into pattern space
/\nRecord/!{                            # if pattern space doesn't match this
/\nPATTERN_END/!{                       # and doesn't match this either
s/\n/ /                                 # replace newline with space
b again                                 # go to : again
}
}
P                                       # print up to first newline
D                                       # then delete up to first newline
}
}' infile
```

In one line:

```
sed '/PATTERN_START/,/PATTERN_END/{//!{/^Record/{x;/^$/d;s/\n/ /g};/^Record/!{H;d}};/PATTERN_END/{x;s/\n/ /g;G;x;s/.*//;x}}' infile
```

and

```
sed '/PATTERN_START/,/PATTERN_END/{//!{: again;N;/\nRecord/!{/\nPATTERN_END/!{s/\n/ /;b again}};P;D}}' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

A Perl way:

```
perl -lne 'if(/^PATTERN_START/){$i=1; %data=(); print; next};
           if(/^PATTERN_END/){
             $i=0;
             if(defined($r)){
               print "$_ @{$data{$_}}" for sort keys(%data)
             }         
           }
           if($i==1){
            if(/^(Record\s*\d+)/){$r=$1;}
            else{push @{$data{$r}},$_}
           }   
           else{print}' file
```

And the same thing as a commented script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

## Read the input file line by line (this is the same as the `-n` flag)
while (<>) {
    ## If this line matches the start pattern, set $i to 1, clear
    ## the %data hash, print the line and skip to the next one.
    if(/^PATTERN_START/){
        $i=1;
        %data=();
        print;
        next
    }
    ## If this line matches the end pattern, set $i to 0
    if(/^PATTERN_END/){
        $i=0;
        ## If we're at the end pattern, we may have saved some
        ## data. This is the case if $r is defined.
        if(defined($r)){
            ## Print the current line, then the saved data associated
            ## with each of the records of this section.
            print "$_ @{$data{$_}}\n" for sort keys(%data)
        }          
    }
    ## If $i is 1, if we're inside a START and END pattern.
    if($i==1){
        ## Remove trailing newlines. This is equivallent to `-l` with
        ## the difference that `-l` also adds a newline to each print()
        ## call. We will add them manually here. 
        chomp;
        ## If this line starts with Record, 0 or more spaces and one
        ## or more numbers, save that as $r. 
        if(/^(Record\s*\d+)/){$r=$1;}
        ## If this line does not start with the above pattern, add it
        ## to the data saved for the current record. 
        else{push @{$data{$r}},$_}
    }
    ## For all other lines, print them as is. 
    else{print}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did three versions of this.

---

#### v1

---

```sh
sed     -e'/^PATTERN_START/!b'  -e:n -eN  \
        -e'/\nPATTERN_END$/!bn' -eh\;s/// \
        -e'x;s/\n[[:print:]]*$//;x'       \
        -e's/\(\nRecord [[:print:]]*\)\{0,1\}\n/\1 /g'  \
        -e'G;P;D'       data
```

That one prints out the *whole* file after only applying edits to the *`Record`* lines which occur between *`PATTERN_{START,END}`*.

---

#### v2

---

```sh
sed   -ne'/\n/P;:n'    \
       -e'/^PATTERN_[OS]/!D'   -eN     \
       -e'/\nPATTERN_END$/!bn' -es///  \
       -e'/^PATTERN_S/s/\(\nRecord [[:print:]]*\)\{0,1\}\n/\1 /g'      \
       -eG\;D  ./data                 ###<gd data> haha
```

That one prints *`Record`* lines within either of *`PATTERN_{(START|OTHER),END}`* but only applies *edits* to those which occur between *`PATTERN_{START,END}`*.

---

#### v3

---

```sh
sed   -ne'/\n/P;:n'    \
       -e'/^PATTERN_START/!D'  -eN     \
       -e'/\nPATTERN_END$/!bn' -es///  \
       -e's/\(\nRecord [[:print:]]*\)\{0,1\}\n/\1 /g'      \
       -eG\;D  ./data
```

And that one *only* edits and *only* prints *`Record`* lines which occur between *`PATTERN_{START,END}`*.

What follows is the output of each after having run your input sample through it. The output samples are presented in reverse order, tbough  shortest to longest.

---

#### v3

---

```
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data Data
Record 2         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data
Record 3         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data Data Data
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data Data
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data
Record 2         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data Data
```

---

#### v2

---

```
Record 1         <- record not between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => do not touch it
Data
Data
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data Data
Record 2         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data
Record 3         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data Data Data
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data Data
Record 1         <- record not between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => do not touch it
Data
Data
Record 2         <- record not between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => do not touch it
Data
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data
Record 2         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data Data
```

---

#### v1

---

```
Blabla
Blabla
PATTERN_OTHER
Record 1         <- record not between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => do not touch it
Data
Data
PATTERN_END
Blabla
PATTERN_START
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data Data
Record 2         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data
Record 3         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data Data Data
PATTERN_START
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line
Data
Data
Data
Record 2         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line
Data
Data
Record 3         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line
Data
Data
Data
Data
Blabla
Blabla
Blabla
Blabla
PATTERN_START
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data Data
PATTERN_START
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line
Data
Data
Data
Blabla
Blabla
PATTERN_OTHER
Record 1         <- record not between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => do not touch it
Data
Data
Record 2         <- record not between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => do not touch it
Data
PATTERN_END
Blabla
Blabla
PATTERN_START
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data
Record 2         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line Data Data Data
PATTERN_START
Record 1         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line
Data
Record 2         <- record between PATTERN_START and PATTERN_END tags => to put in one line
Data
Data
Data
Blabla
Blabla
```