# Shell script print single line output based on starting and ending parameter present in single line or multiline

Tags: sed, text-formatting

My File is:

```
"abc"..,,xyz 123 "New york".."END" <- # Print this entire line as starts with " and ends with "END"
"mnh".....blahblah                 <- # dont print this line and hold til "END" is
"rew"..?/.."1324.75 United            # found and once it is found, merge multi-
 States"??..."END"                    # lines to single line without changes
```

Desired output:

```
"abc"..,,xyz 123 "New york".."END"
"mnh".....blahblah"rew"..?/.."1324.75 United States"??..."END"
```

Found the below `sed` which does everything with *start_pattern* as `"` and *end_pattern* as `"END"`, but
it breaks when intermediate line starts with `"`; here when it starts with `"rew"`, before the *end_pattern* is found.

```
sed -n '/^"/,/^"END"/{
        //!{H;/{x;s/\n\([^\n]*\)$/\1/;x}};
        /^"/{h};/"END"/{x;p};d
        }' file
```

Link: [How to remove newlines between data of each record which are located between 2 patterns?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211309/how-to-remove-newlines-between-data-of-each-record-which-are-located-between-2-p/211366)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join a line to the following one if it does not end in `"END"` using sed as follows:

```
sed -e :a -e '/"END"$/!N; s/\n//; ta' file
```

Ex. given `file` as

```
"abc"..,,xyz 123 "New york".."END"
"mnh".....blahblah
"rew"..?/.."1324.75 United
States"??..."END"
```

then

```
$ sed -e :a -e '/"END"$/!N; s/\n//; ta' file
"abc"..,,xyz 123 "New york".."END"
"mnh".....blahblah"rew"..?/.."1324.75 UnitedStates"??..."END"
```

Note that (in line with your desired output) this does **not** add a space in place of the newline when it makes the join - if you actually want the space, then simply change `s/\n//` to `s/\n/ /`

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
awk -v RS='"END"\n' -v FS='\n' -v ORS='"END"\n' -v OFS=' ' '{ $1=$1 };1' file
```

or the equivalent

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN { ORS=RS="\"END\"\n"; FS="\n" } { $1 = $1 }; 1' file
```

(which uses the fact that `OFS=' '` is the default anyway).

This is a *really short* `awk` command that simply reformats your input from one set of record and field separators to another set of record and field separators.  Most of the magic is how the input record and field separators (`RS` and `FS`) are changed into new output separators (`ORS` and `OFS`).

Your input document,

```
"abc"..,,xyz 123 "New york".."END"
"mnh".....blahblah
"rew"..?/.."1324.75 United
States"??..."END"
```

uses `"END"\n` as the record separator, and `\n` (newline) as field separator.

Changing the field separator to   (a space) would be enough to solve your issue.

The actual *code* just makes `awk` reformat the record so that the new field separator (`OFS`) is used in place of the old (`FS`).

The result would be

```
"abc"..,,xyz 123 "New york".."END"
"mnh".....blahblah "rew"..?/.."1324.75 United States"??..."END"
```

---

Technically, using a multi-character value for `RS` invokes *unspecified* behavior according to the [POSIX specification for the `awk` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).  Most (all?) current `awk` implementations treat a multi-character value in `RS` as a regular expression.